# Child terms from multiple parents?

Tags: terms, get-children

I'm using isotope to filter a custom post type. But I only want the child taxonomies of 2 particular parents.  I have it working nicely for one parent, but I'm not sure how to modify the array to allow for 2 parents.

```
$terms = get_terms('speight_plans', array('parent' => 16)); // you can use any taxonomy, instead of just 'category'
    $count = count($terms); //How many are they?
        if ( $count > 0 ){  //If there are more than 0 terms
            foreach ( $terms as $term ) {  //for each term:
                echo '<button class="button" data-filter=".'.$term->slug.'">' . $term->name . '</button>';
                //create a list item with the current term slug for sorting, and name for label
            }
        }
```

I tried doing

```
array('parent' => 16, 15));
```

But that still only showed the children of parent 16.

Any help you can afford would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can filter the generated SQL query through the [`terms_clauses` filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/terms_clauses/) before the SQL query is executed. What we will be doing is to introduce a new parameter called `wpse_parents` which will accept an array of parent term ID's to get children from. Note, this new parameter works exactly the same as the build-in parameter, `parent`, as it will return only direct children of the parent.

### THE FILTER

The code is commented for easy understanding and basic description of what a particular piece of code is doing. Note, all code requires at least PHP 5.4

```
add_filter( 'terms_clauses', function ( $pieces, $taxonomies, $args )
{
    // Bail if we are not currently handling our specified taxonomy
    if ( !in_array( 'speight_plans', $taxonomies ) )
        return $pieces;

    // Check if our custom argument, 'wpse_parents' is set, if not, bail
    if (    !isset ( $args['wpse_parents'] )
         || !is_array( $args['wpse_parents'] )
    ) 
        return $pieces;

    // If  'wpse_parents' is set, make sure that 'parent' and 'child_of' is not set
    if (    $args['parent']
         || $args['child_of']
    )
        return $pieces;

    // Validate the array as an array of integers
    $parents = array_map( 'intval', $args['wpse_parents'] );

    // Loop through $parents and set the WHERE clause accordingly
    $where = [];
    foreach ( $parents as $parent ) {
        // Make sure $parent is not 0, if so, skip and continue
        if ( 0 === $parent )
            continue;

        $where[] = " tt.parent = '$parent'";
    }

    if ( !$where )
        return $pieces;

    $where_string = implode( ' OR ', $where );
    $pieces['where'] .= " AND ( $where_string ) ";

    return $pieces;
}, 10, 3 );
```

Just a note, the filter is build in such a way that it does not allow the `parent` and `child_of` parameters being set. If any of those parameters are set, the filter bails early and is not applied

### BASIC USAGE

If you need to query child terms from terms 15 and 16, you can run the following query to achieve your goal

```
$args = [
    'wpse_parents' => [15, 16]
];
$terms = get_terms( 'speight_plans', $args );
```

Comment: This was perfect! Thank you loads! I added the filter to my functions.php and integrated the arg into the code I already had.

Comment: Glad it worked. Enjoy ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I can think about the `get_term_children()` function. You can use that function two times to retrieve 2 array of child terms id of two parent terms. Then you can merge them to one array and pass that array to `get_terms`

```
get_terms('speight_plans', array('include' => $child_terms_arr));
```