# Get children of taxonomies

Tags: custom-taxonomy, list, get-children

```
    $terms = get_terms([
        'taxonomy' => array('Movies, Musics, Books, Games'),
        'parent' => 0,
        'depth'=> 2,
        'hide_empty' => false,
    ]);
    $sorted_terms = [];
    if ( $terms ) {
        foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
            $sorted_term = [
                'WP_Term'            => $term, // the global term
                'icon'               => get_field( 'logo', $term->taxonomy . '_' . $term->term_id ),
                'srating'               => get_field( 'rating', $term->taxonomy . '_' . $term->term_id ),
                'carrentActiveClass' => '',
                'count'              => (int) wpse340250_term_count( $term, 'sikayet' ),
                // everything you will need later here
            ];
///// and my code continue
```

in the above code I can get terms of different taxonomies. But I am trying to get children of taxonomy terms. Can any one help me please

```
'parent' => 0,
        'depth'=> 2,
```

did not work

Comment: By setting `'parent' => 0`, you are querying for the top-level taxonomies.

Comment: when i change 0 to 1 , it doesnt show anything

Comment: wooow I uderstant now,  'parent' => parent ID . thank you vey much  Sharif Mohammad Eunus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not actually sure what you are trying to achieve with the code. I would write something like this to get the child terms

```
 $terms = get_terms([
        'taxonomy' => array('Movies, Musics, Books, Games'),
        'parent' => 0,
        'hide_empty' => false,
 ]);

if ( ! empty( $terms ) && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ) {

    foreach ($terms as $term) {

        $child_term =  get_term_children( $term->term_id, $term->taxonomy )

         //your code here
    }

}
```

Comment: its better thank you

Comment: Sharif Mohammad Eunus can you tell me how can i add multible ids to parent. Please

Comment: 'depth' => 4, not work

Comment: Well, I can see the `depth` parameter on `get_terms()` will not work. Accepted parameters are listed here: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/#parameters

Comment: but there is depth parameter in the list. then why doesnt work

Comment: Sorry, that was a wrong link. Here's the correct onehttps://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_term_query/__construct/

Comment: what would you advise me to fix my problem

Comment: You can't set multiple `parent` at the same time as it accepts `(int|string)`. You can run a loop on child terms to get grandchild terms. Could you explain a bit more about your problem?

Comment: Please also check this, there is a solution here to call multiple parents: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/221667/child-terms-from-multiple-parents

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118820/discussion-between-gidromasservis-qsc-and-sharif-mohammad-eunus).